# when the border of the table rmoves when increasing or decreasing the padding value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my fsiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/n7po3uv7/1/

i have two buttons: one for zoom in, and one for zoom out.

this is the jquery code for them:

```
$("#zoomIn").on('click', function () {
        var previousValue = parseInt($(".table tr td").css("padding-top"));
        if (previousValue < 80) {
            previousValue = previousValue + 10;
            $(".table tr td").css('padding', previousValue);

            var fontSize = parseInt($(".table tr td").css("font-size"));
            fontSize = fontSize + 10;
            $(".table tr td").css("font-size", fontSize);
        }
    });
    $("#zoomOut").on('click', function () {
        var previousValue = parseInt($(".table tr td").css("padding-top"));
        if (previousValue > 30) {
            previousValue = previousValue - 10;
            $(".table tr td").css('padding', previousValue);

            var fontSize = parseInt($(".table tr td").css("font-size"));
            fontSize = fontSize - 10;
            $(".table tr td").css("font-size", fontSize);
        }
    });
```

#### The problem

the border between the `td` removes after three clicks or zoom out or zoom in. could you check please?

#### before

[image]

#### After

[image]
please notice in the second image how the border is gone between the second cell

Comment: @chipChocolate.py you need to zoom many times in order to remove the border, in my firefox the border removes after three zoom in

Comment: It would be easier for us to understand if you add an image explaining the issue.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce the issue in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on OS X 10.10. Can you try in a different browser on your machine? Do you have any firefox extensions?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py i added an image

Comment: @Kierkegaurd i added a sceenshopt for the problem

Comment: @Kierkegaurd I tried the jsfiddle on a Win7 PC using latest versions of IE, Firefox, Chrome and I could not see the border artifact.

Comment: Unable to replicate problem. Using latest versions of Safari, Chrome and Firefox on rMBP OS X 10.10.

Comment: What OS are you using Marco? What version of Firefox? Nothing seems to be wrong with your code, so it may be a version-specific browser issue.

Comment: i am using windows 7, firefox 34, i don't have previllage to install chrome here